# Parametrise $z_0^2 + \cdots + z_3^2 = 0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

Find a function $f:\mathbb{CP}^1 \times \mathbb{CP}^1 \longrightarrow \mathbb{CP}^3$ with image

$$
\{[z_0:z_1:z_2:z_3] \in \mathbb{CP}^3 \mid z_0^2 + \cdots + z_3^2 = 0\}.
$$

I have got no idea how to get the solution. I know it has to involve some imaginary $i$ because otherwise, when we plug in purely real input $([x_0:x_1],[y_0:y_1])$, it's not possible to obtain $z_0^2 + \cdots + z_3^2 = 0$.

Comment: **HINT**: Over $\Bbb C$, the quadratic form $z_0^2+\dots+z_3^2$ is equivalent to the quadratic form $z_0z_3\pm z_1z_2$.

Comment: Is it like un-diagonalisation?

Comment: LOL, sure. It's just making an obvious change of basis in $\Bbb C^4$.